# Why I cannot get transaction from genesis block

Tags: raw-transaction, genesis-block

When I run command

> getrawtransaction
>   4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b

in my bitcoin-qt console (or bitcoind), I get

> No information available about transaction (code -5)

But I can get raw data about any other transaction.

Here is link to blockchain.info: https://blockchain.info/ru/tx/4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to my question there: [Why can’t the genesis block coinbase be spent?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/why-cant-the-genesis-block-coinbase-be-spent)

> For some reason, Satoshi decided not to add the coinbase transaction
>   from the genesis block to the global transaction database. Thus all
>   the nodes in the network would reject the block.