# Can I look for transaction in the genesis block?

Tags: protocol, testing, genesis-block

I'm testing bitcoin and, as an experiment, I added a transaction after the coinbase to the genesis block. However, it appears that it can't be searched with the rpc commands. Why is that?
I already read that the coinbase in the genesis block can't be spent and this is ok, but what about the other transactions?

Comment: Related: [Why can't the genesis block coinbase be spent?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/why-cant-the-genesis-block-coinbase-be-spent).  Your transaction must be attempting to spend that coinbase (because at that stage there is nothing else to spend) which surely would make it invalid?

Answer (score -1):

There are no other transactions in the Genesis block. For all intents nothing in that block is worthwhile inquiring information about.

Comment: There's a transaction in his, because he added it. (So his genesis block is different, and he effectively has an altcoin.)

Comment: I see no need to be rude. Altcoins and other cryptocurrencies are on topic here.

Comment: Users that can't debug issues of their own making shouldn't be trying to edit highly complicated cryptocurrencies.

Comment: @goatse are you for real? Even the core developers of bitcoin go out bug hunting. I really hope you're trolling.

Comment: I'm serious. No core developer bothers with this sort of nonsense. Altcoins never have and never will contribute anything to the core client. They are pump and dumps without limit.